# LINQ to Twitter Support Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: linq, twitter, xamarin, linq-to-twitter

I wonder if anyone try using LINQ to Twitter 3.0 beta with Xamarin.iOS ? Joe Mayo provide an example of how using the library with Xamarin.Android However i can't seems to get that work on IOS > it's compiling, but it crashes at runtime because it's looking for not-existing assemblies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a blog, [LINQ to Twitter Runs On Xamarin.iOS](http://geekswithblogs.net/WinAZ/archive/2013/12/06/linq-to-twitter-runs-on-xamarin.ios.aspx). A couple days ago, I also posted [v3.0 as a pre-release on NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/linqtotwitter).